# How to express the total distance between two column vectors containing row vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two column vectors:

\begin{equation}
p=\left[\begin{array}{c}
{\left[x_{1}, y_{1}\right]} \\
{\left[x_{2}, y_{2}\right]} \\
\vdots \\
{\left[x_{n}, y_{n}\right]}
\end{array}\right], 
\quad 
\hat{p}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
{\left[\hat{x}_{1}, \hat{y}_{1}\right]} \\
{\left[\hat{x}_{2}, \hat{y}_{2}\right]} \\
\vdots \\
{\left[\hat{x}_{n}, \hat{y}_{n}\right]}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

How can I formulate the accumulated eucleidian distance across all child row vectors and their corresponding estimates?

Byaccumulated eucleidian distance I mean:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\sqrt{\left(\hat{x}_{1}-x_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(\hat{y}_{1}-y_{1}\right)^{2}}+ \\
\sqrt{\left(\hat{x}_{2}-x_{2}\right)^{2}+\left(\hat{y}_{2}-y_{2}\right)^{2}}+ \\
\vdots \\
\sqrt{\left(\hat{x}_{n}-x_{n}\right)^{2}+\left(\hat{y}_{n}-y_{n}\right)^{2}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Does this make sense?:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in \mathcal{n}}\left\|\boldsymbol{p}_{i}-\hat{\boldsymbol{p}}_{i}\right\|
\end{equation}

Comment: What is "accumulated euclidean distance"?

Comment: Updated with an explanation

Comment: Then yes, your expression is correct. Although slight notational inaccuracy, it should be $\sum_{i=1}^n$ instead of $\sum_{i\in n}$. The latter notation seems to imply that $n$ is a set, which it's not.